# How to approach the stigma of not having a math degree?

Tags: soft-question

I am a faculty member in a department that is not mathematics, but is highly-ranked in my field.  I greatly enjoy working with mathematicians, and have had a number of successful collaborations.

Sadly, when I first meet a new mathematician I am often met with  skepticism because I do not have the right pedigree, i.e., neither my bachelor's degree nor my PhD come from a math department.  Often I find myself in a situation where, rather than exploring fun an interesting ideas together, I get things "explained" to me as though I am an outside amateur with pie-in-the-sky ideas.

Ironically, I almost completed a double-major in math as an undergrad, but rather than fulfilling the last few course requirements, I was advised to take the upper-elective math electives that I found most interesting unless I "really needed the math diploma for a job or something."  In grad school, I didn't do math quals of course, but did take plenty of courses in the math department (and from the best of them!).  And did a thesis co-advised by a mathematician.  Not to mention the enormous amount of time I've spent learning on my own, and the perspectives that I've been so fortunate to absorb from my collaborators in math, and from the numerous conferences and workshops I've participated in.  I don't regret the path I've taken (it's been exciting and fulfilling), but I still find myself wishing I had the damn pedigree.

So, question: *what's the easiest way to convince a new mathematician that I belong to his/her tribe?*  (So that we can just get on to the important business of exploring fun and interesting ideas...)

Comment: Some advice: be active in mathematics -- publish!!
I checked the Zentralblatt MATH database, and it seems you
have so far published no paper in the field. So -- change this! -- Once you have published some good results in reasonable journals, mathematicians will respect you as a colleague.

Comment: "Fred E. Katt" is not my real name!

Comment: Not sure why this question is off-topic.

Comment: @FredE.Katt: this question is deemed off-topic because its content is not plain math research, albeit really related to math research. Maybe you could try on http://academia.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @FredE.Katt : This site isn't intended for "personal advice" type questions.  Some are welcome, but those typically concern topics that are of broad interest to academic mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks Andy. my feeling is that this question is of significant interest to many of us doing research in mathematics who do not have a math degree. I.e., it is not meant as a question of personal advice.

Comment: @FredE.Katt : That's not the target audience of MO.  Their technical questions are welcome here as long as they are on a high level, but the few career questions that are welcome here concern the careers of academic mathematicians.

Comment: @Andy: thanks for your consideration of this question here and on the meta page. I do find the response a bit ironic, though: I am a research mathematician. My question was precisely about how to avoid the stigma that is now being expressed by the closing of this question.

Comment: I'm sorry your question was closed - your situation is actually not too different from the one experienced by PhD candidates! The quickest way is to convince the mathematician that you know your stuff already. If someone condescendingly says "well, there is a famous theorem relating curvature to Euler characteristic", you should immediately respond with "how is Gauss-Bonnet relevant here?" instead of with sighs of frustration. We're a laconic lot in general, and would be happier to not have to explain things :)

Comment: Contrary to the previous comment, I think that the (perceived or actual) stigma that the OP describes in his or her post is a separate issue from the closing of this question.

Comment: Also, perhaps I have been lucky, but I have found that demonstrating technical competence a good way to mitigate _"a situation where, rather than exploring fun an interesting ideas together, I get things "explained" to me as though I am an outside amateur with pie-in-the-sky ideas."_

Comment: Fred E. Katt is not a research mathematician. If you want respect and the benefit of the doubt on career/personal advice on MO, use your real name.

Comment: In some universities (including mine), faculty members in one department can have "courtesy appointments" in another. These are 0% appointments, with no salary, no teaching load, and no other duties. They serve as an indication that the person interacts, in a serious way, with faculty in that second department. You might check whether your university has such arrangements.

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2130/12357

Comment: I think Stefan Kohl has answered your question well.  Once you have (refereed) publications, you are "officially a real mathematician."

Comment: Thank you all for your responses (despite the question being "put on hold." :-))  This is exactly the kind of information I was seeking.  Thanks again!